# Anti-re tactics or radare problem while debugging

Tags: debugging, radare2, anti-debugging

Here's the target application: https://www.sa-mp.com/download.php

While live debugging, the Windows application is starting a few threads, and Cutter auto breaks after entrypoint for a reason I'm not sure of. The samp server application only throws that it cannot load server.cfg. Is it due to threads, or is it anti-re tactics?

All auto settings.
Cutter v1.10.3x64
Windows 10 Home

Comment: samp_served.exe doesn't give me error, when analyzed all (aaa) using radare2

Comment: I know, but try live debugging. It stops at some random instructions (not just the entry point) on start and it does not stop on specified breakpoint